# How do I view which process is using a particular file?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Can anyone suggest a program that can tell me which process is using which files? I need a GUI program that I can run on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 5):

"Ever wondered which program has a particular file or directory open? Now you can find out. Process Explorer shows you information about which handles and DLLs processes have opened or loaded."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx